# Loading ALL textures from a URL in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, model, three.js, 3d, textures

it's my first time with threeJS and I am working on a texture/model viewer.
All textures and models are lying on a VPS. The html is served with Express.

This partially works:

```
var renderItem = {       //All links to all textures
  body: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/body.png",
  display: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/display.png",
  info: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/clear.png",
  model: "P250.obj",
  s1: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/VoxEminorHoloKatowice2015.png",
  s2: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/VoxEminorHoloKatowice2015.png",
  s3: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/VoxEminorHoloKatowice2014.png",
  s4: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/VoxEminorHoloKatowice2014.png",
  skin: "http://188.166.72.201:8000/w5u6vq5f.jpg"
}

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 30;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.5;
    controls.enableZoom = true;

var fillLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(15658734,1.6)
    fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100)

var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(15658734,1,10)
    backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize()

scene.add(fillLight);
scene.add(backLight);

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setTexturePath('/models/');
    mtlLoader.setPath('/models/');
    mtlLoader.load('item.mtl', function (materials) { 

      scene.background = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load("bg.jpg")

      materials.preload();

      materials.materials.skin.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.skin)
      materials.materials.body.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.body)
      materials.materials.display.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.display)
      materials.materials.s1.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.s1)
      materials.materials.s2.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.s2)
      materials.materials.s3.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.s3)
      materials.materials.s4.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.s4)
      materials.materials.info.map = (new THREE.TextureLoader).load(renderItem.info)

      materials.materials.s1.transparent = true;
      materials.materials.s2.transparent = true;
      materials.materials.s3.transparent = true;
      materials.materials.s4.transparent = true;

      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
          objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
          objLoader.setPath('/models/');
          objLoader.load(renderItem.model, function (object) {
          scene.add(object);
      });

});

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

The MTL file i am importing here is mostly a dummy since this seems to give me access to the materials in some way. The textures mentioned in that mtl to exist but are only white.

My model consists of 8 meshes in total. Those were named "skin, body, display, s1, s2, ..." in the CAD software. ThreeJS also seems to recognize those names since some textures are being applied as they should.

Well ... the base texture (renderItem.skin) is being applied where it should. The stickers on top of it (they are basically textures on 4 flat meshes that are offset by a bit from the bigger mesh) aren't visible.

I have to set those four materials to transparent = true since the rectangular mesh should only be rendered where the png texture is non-transparent.

Chrome is loading the right textures for all materials (I can see that on the sources tab in the dev tools) but doesn't apply them right.

One thing I noticed: For some models, textures are distorted (even for the base texture) and in one example, I saw one of the non-working stickers being so much distorted that it was almost invisible.

Long story short: My textures seems to find their right place, but seem to be so stretched or wrongly applied that they become pretty much invisible.

The viewer is live. In this example. The base texture got applied but is broken around the magazine. There should also be 4 stickers on this model. Dev Tools shows them loaded, but they arent visible.

http://3d.mrinka.org/three?s=277l8y69

The model in the threeJS viewer is supposed to look similar to this one I made with the SketchFab API.

https://sketchfab.com/models/8fb464cb51b94c11924d4c652995f335

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I tripple checked the uv wrapping and tried multiple render and cad modelling softwares. All, Rhino, Blender, KeyShot, Cinema and Sketchfab aren't having any problems applying this texture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSuPY.png

Edit2: Getting really weird now. If I set up the scene using an mtl loader with a simple mtl that links to the texture, I get this (good mapping, the white areas are supposed to be like that.) result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7pFZ.png

If I set a 5 second timeout, create a new material with the same texture and apply that one to every mesh int the sccene , it turns into the UV glitch i mentioned above. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GblgZ.png

Comment: Your stretchy textures look like a badly UV-unwrapped model. Did you make sure your UVs are mapped correctly to the textures you're importing?

Comment: @Marquizzo Yep. The sketchfab model has the same texture and model. It's definitely mapped correctly.